# Getting "pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure" when updating password after password expires

Tags: linux, unix, passwd

When I expire a users password with `chage -d 0 USER` the user is able to log in and they are prompt with Current Unix password. When the user puts anything into the password the session is closed. inside the `/var/log/secure` there is a log entry `pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure`

If the user manually sets a password after I reset their password they have no issues.

What can I look at to solve this issue where expire causes `pam_unix` to freak out and prevent the user from updating their expired password?

```
Aug 14 20:34:38 ip-172-30-0-196 sshd[27369]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.1.1.123  user=XXX
Aug 14 20:34:40 ip-172-30-0-196 sshd[27369]: Failed password for XXX from 10.1.92.123 port 51240 ssh2
```

Answer (score 2):

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

Changed line:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation no
```

To:

```
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
```